# How to sort keys in dictionary if values are same?

Tags: python-3.x

How to sort keys in dictionary if values are same ?

```
dictionary={}
count={'S': 28, 'O': 24, 'C': 20, 'W': 20, 'M': 17, 'T': 17, 'G': 17, 'K': 14, 'E': 11, 'N': 10, 'F': 8, 'D': 7, 'Y': 7, 'L': 6, 'I': 6, 'Q': 6, 'J': 5, 'A': 2, 'U': 2, 'V': 2, 'R': 2, 'Z': 1}
for key, value in sorted(count.items(),reverse=True, key=lambda item: (item[1], item[0])):
    #print ("%s: %s" % (key, value))
    dictionary[key] = value
print(dictionary)


OUTPUT:{'s': 28, 'o': 24, 'w': 20, 'c': 20, 't': 17, 'm': 17, 'g': 17, 'k': 14, 'e': 11, 'n': 10, 'f': 8, 'y': 7, 'd': 7, 'q': 6, 'l': 6, 'i': 6, 'j': 5, 'v': 2, 'u': 2, 'r': 2, 'a': 2, 'z': 1}


BUT i want like this:{'s': 28, 'o': 24, 'c': 20, 'w': 20, 'g': 17, 'm': 17, 't': 17, 'k': 14, 'e': 11, 'n': 10, 'f': 8, 'd': 7, 'y': 7, 'i': 6, 'l': 6, 'q': 6, 'j': 5, 'a': 2, 'r': 2, 'u': 2, 'v': 2, 'z': 1}
```

Comment: Creating another, sorted Dictionary - this would only work for CPython 3.6 and 3.7  onward as they keep the original insert order. Dictionarys are inheritently unordered. - are you just looking for a pretty print function?

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse the order of only the numeric item by negating it instead of specifying `reverse=True`:

```
dictionary={}
count={'S': 28, 'O': 24, 'C': 20, 'W': 20, 'M': 17, 'T': 17, 'G': 17, 'K': 14, 'E': 11, 'N': 10, 'F': 8, 'D': 7, 'Y': 7, 'L': 6, 'I': 6, 'Q': 6, 'J': 5, 'A': 2, 'U': 2, 'V': 2, 'R': 2, 'Z': 1}
for key, value in sorted(count.items(), key=lambda item: (-item[1], item[0])):
    #print ("%s: %s" % (key, value))
    dictionary[key] = value
print(dictionary)
```

This outputs:

```
{'S': 28, 'O': 24, 'C': 20, 'W': 20, 'G': 17, 'M': 17, 'T': 17, 'K': 14, 'E': 11, 'N': 10, 'F': 8, 'D': 7, 'Y': 7, 'I': 6, 'L': 6, 'Q': 6, 'J': 5, 'A': 2, 'R': 2, 'U': 2, 'V': 2, 'Z': 1}
```

Comment: That Output:     {'Z': 1, 'A': 2, 'R': 2, 'U': 2, 'V': 2, 'J': 5, 'I': 6, 'L': 6, 'Q': 6, 'D': 7, 'Y': 7, 'F': 8, 'N': 10, 'E': 11, 'K': 14, 'G': 17, 'M': 17, 'T': 17, 'C': 20, 'W': 20, 'O': 24, 'S': 28}

Comment: Did you add `-` to `item[1]`?

Comment: you should just do `dict(sorted([(i,j)for i,j in count.items()],key = lambda x: (-x[1],x[0])))`

Comment: @NarasimhaPonnam which version of python do you use? (3.4, 3.5, etc) Insertion order will be kept guaranteed only if you use python3.7 - https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html. For python3.6 it is implementation detail

Comment: Thank you @blhsing

Comment: @NarasimhaPonnam Glad to be of help. Can you mark this answer as accepted if you find it to be correct?

Comment: i am useing 3.6 @MikhailStepanov

Comment: At 3.7 @blhsing code works for me.What implementation you use? CPython?